# feedback based on multiple measurments

Tags: stim

I know that Stim has the option to play a conditioned pulse based on a previous measurment by writing `CZ rec[-1] 1` which does a Z gate on qb1 if the last measurment is 1. Now I am wondering whether you could do feedback based on two previous measurments, say if the last two readouts gave 1, play a conditioned pulse on qb1. I tried something like `CZ rec[-1]*rec[-2] 1`, but this isn't supported unfortunately.
Does anyone have an idea if this is possible in Stim?
Any help is much appreachiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stim.TableauSimulator` to implement this kind of feedback:

```
import stim
sim = stim.TableauSimulator()
sim.h(0)
sim.h(1)
a = sim.measure(0)
b = sim.measure(1)
if a and b:
    sim.x(2)
```

A `stim.Circuit` has no way to specify double-controlled Paulis. The underlying reason is because double-controlled Paulis prevent bulk sampling based on diffing a reference sample against a Pauli error frame (what `stim.FlipSimulator` does).

The issue is that a double-controlled Pauli allows errors to escape the simple world of parity flips. A bit flip error propagating into a measurement that's part of a double-controlled Pauli will result in the bit flip error propagating into a bit flip error times a controlled bit flip error. Another double-controlled Pauli can then grow the controlled bit flip error into a doubly-controlled bit flip error. Another double-controlled Pauli can grow the error into a triply-controlled bit flip error. The errors are no longer restricted to being a set of bit flips. They are growing in complexity. They can become equivalent to any classical computation. Tracking all that complexity would be extremely expensive.